# How to get only the elements which are not string from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to get only the elements from the list, which are not strings. Instead it gives an empty list. Why is this?

```
a = ['# this is a comment', 1, '# another comment', 2]
data = [x for x in a if type(x) == 'str']
print(data)
```

Output: `[]`

Expected output: `[1, 2]`

Comment: It doesn't work because `'str'!=str`. Remove the quotes

Comment: Note that even if this were correct, it would still be wrong because you do `==` when you want to do `!=`.

Comment: 1) Your if statement contains: ```if type(x) == 'str'```
So you compare type(x) with 'str'. Your expected type of x is str object. The desired comparison you want to make is type(x) and str object.
2) You want to put into the list x that are other type than string so you need to add negation to your if statement.
3) It is good practice to use 'is' instead of '==' during types comparison. Explanation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-operator-python/
You should change line 2 to:
```data = [x for x in a if type(x) is not str]```

Answer (score 3):

The type is not `'str'` (c.f. JavaScript's `typeof` operator, which *does* return strings), it's `str`.

```py
a = ['# this is a comment', 1,'# another comment', 2]
print([x for x in a if type(x) == 'str'])  # compares a type object to a string, no results
print([x for x in a if type(x) == str])  # compares a type object to a type object, 2 results
```

`isinstance(x, str)` would be a better way to check the type though, since it takes care of subclasses too.

Answer (score 2):

Better way to do this would be to use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
a = ['# this is a comment', 1, '# another comment', 2]
data = [x for x in a if not isinstance(x, str)]
print(data)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [1, 2]
> ```

The reason why your original code doesn't work is that comparing to the string `'str'` is not the same as comparing to the type `str`. Also you have a `==` in your code, but it should be `!=`, if you only want the ones which are *not* strings.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing str type to literal string.

Also you should do this in pythonic way. Use in-bulit function like filter

```
a = ['# this is a comment', 1,'# another comment', 2]
int_list = list(filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x, str), a))
>>> int_list
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

**code change**

1. 'str' to str
2. == to !=

**Updated Code**

```
a = ['# this is a comment', 1, '# another comment', 2]
data = [x for x in a if type(x) != str]
print(data)
```

**Reason**

1. Use str object instead of string
2. To check non string values, check with not equal sign

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
a = ['# this is a comment', 1,'# another comment', 2]
data = [x for x in a if type(x)!= str]
print (data)
```

**Output** :

```
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in method `isinstance` to check the type of an object-

```
 a = ['# this is a comment', 1, '# another comment', 2]
 data = [x for x in a if not isinstance(x, str)]
 print (data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `type(something)` returns the actual class of `something`, not a string of the class name.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers describe what you should do instead, I try to focus on your question.

[`type(x)` returns a type object.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) A type object is the object which describes the type of an object, such as `str`, `int` etc. While their name representation is usually the same as their name (i. e. they have a `__name__` attribute which describes their name and which also is returned when they are converted to a string), they don't compare equal to that string.

For example:

```
>>> int
<class 'int'>
>>> int.__name__
'int'
```

Note that it would be also wrong (or: not clean) to get the `__name__` of the object and compare to that what you need, because there could be other types with the same name, but distinct of what you expect.

The correct way would indeed be to use `isinstance()` as [pointed out by @ruohola](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57884172/296974).